# Visual Studio 2019 Very Slow and Not Responding for second on add folder or add cs

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-core-2.2

Everything was perfect and suddenly on Visual Studio 2019 .net core 2.2 project - add new folder, add new file on that folder is too slow, also have "Not responding" for a second.

I hade the same problem on other project, also didn't found solution.

Right click on any folder in the project -> add new folder - 6 seconds + 1 sec Not responding
Rename that folder - 7 seconds  + 1 sec Not responding
The same as add new .cs

Also search in google a lot, all the comments from Microsoft - thank you for the feedback...